# Excel Manual Cell Value Equals to In Range of Cells to be Used With Other Condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

In conditional formatting you can select a range of cells such as A1:C3 go to highlighted cell rules and equal to, so that for example any 0 would be red.

But I want to combined this condition with another one and so I have to write my own formula using and AND for example I tried:

```
=AND($A$1:$C$3=0, $D$5=5)
```

But this will apply the condition to all the cells in the range only if all the cells in the range equal 0 and D5 is equal to 5.

However, I want it to only apply it to the cells that equal 0 without having to make a rule for every cell in the range.

Comment: `=AND(A1:C3=0, $D$5=5)` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
=AND(A1=0,$D$5=5)
```

The conditional formatting will iterate the range itself.  One rule for the whole range with the formula relatively referencing the upper left cell.

[image]